# Why Javascript Eval is slower, when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, eval

So i'm trying to create my own JS framework just for my own pleasure (and probably then convert into usefullness) and I most of the time focus on generating JS dynamicly (since having higher level with JS as language-in-the-middle is bad idea, IMO)

And I got into one trouble. I was trying to do following

```
var f = null;
var converted = "f = function(){ <do something here>";
for(var x in list)
 converted+=list[x];
converted+="};";
eval(converted);
```

So this pretty much writes constructed function to f, that I can later execute.

But here's the catch - it runs slower, than if I just write code of f completely in file, which is very strange. Let me explain why it's strange to me: when you just run eval each time, Chrome precompiler (or whatever browser precompiler - chrome is what I target) can't cache-compile the code, because it expects, that it will change with each run.

However, when you save this to a function, it creates a new VM machine file, because after you saved the function's code, you can't change it. So why, when I do such eval, it runs slower than normal execution? I mean after code was executed more than once. Why this should matter?

PS: The method I had shown above, works faster that eval-ing each time. So I don't understand why stopwatches show time inbetween, again, ignoring first 1-10 calls

PPS: Test case: http://jsperf.com/evaluated-function-vs-real-function/2

Comment: `when you save this to a function` - how are you saving it to a function? From the code you posted, I don't see the evaluated code being converted to a function.

Comment: beleive me, it is. When you eval variable "converted", f=function()... is executed, which writes new function into variable f

Comment: When I test it, I see no performance difference between a regular function and one created using `eval`: http://jsperf.com/evaluated-function-vs-real-function

Comment: Ah, never mind - I wasn't seeing `f` referenced anywhere outside of your evalled code.

Comment: That probably depends on the engine. How did you benchmark your function exactly?

Comment: here: http://jsperf.com/evaluated-function-vs-real-function/2

Comment: Dammit, on some test on the same page, it's faster, on some cases, it's slower... can't understand

Comment: It is likely that using the Function constructor would help, here. Seriously, using eval this way is super dangerous, and considered harmful. At least you should assign the function value as the result of the eval call, i.e.,
`var converted = "var f = function() { ...";`
`...`
`converted += "}; f;"`
`var f = eval(converted);`
But I would suggest
`var f = new Function(converted);`
where `converted` is only the body of your function.

Comment: I create code where no user input can be, so no worries there. Thanks for advice tho

Comment: @AndrewYukhymchak, Have you considered the overhead of calling the `eval` function? The question you should be asking is "Should Eval be faster?"

Comment: The jsperf link is dead, but I can confirm that while in Chrome, everything is the same speed, in Node: (1) `new Function("...")` is as fast as the original code, (2) eval(iife) is 3 times slower, (3) eval(arbitrayCode) is 10 times slower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eval` is basically unoptimizable because the compiler doesn't know what it's doing. Even if you save it into a function, the compiler has to opt out a lot of optimizations, because changing your code in a certain way might break the eval function.

This is why, usually, when you need to do an eval, you do it in another function : that way, the compiler can be sure you didn't modify local scope in the `eval`, and optimizes a lot better.

JS VMs are really a lot about heuristics. They try to guess what you want to do, and optimize for the general case. `eval` (or `new Function`) prevent them to do a lot of that.

`Function.new` **might** be a little faster, because the compiler will know it won't try to modify the scope.

---

**ALSO** ! Note that `eval` might act a little differently than what you're used to. For example, `eval('a')` and `(0, eval)('a')` are **not the same** :

I'll demonstrate it with this

```
window.a = 5;
void function () {
  var a = 1;
  eval('a = 2');
  console.log(a);
  console.log(window.a);
}();
```

This will print `1` then `5`

```
window.a = 5;
void function () {
  var a = 1;
  (0,eval)('a = 2'); // <- this line has changed
  console.log(a);
  console.log(window.a);
}();
```

Whereas, this will print `1` then `2`.

You can also read this : [Global eval, what are the options](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/).

Comment: So if I do `new Function('<CODE>')` I can get better results?

Comment: It might, a little bit. I added a comment about that.

Comment: Also, `eval` is strange, so I added a "note" about that

Comment: strangely, new Function is slower: http://jsperf.com/evaluated-function-vs-real-function/2

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that in the past, too. But that might be vm-dependant.

Comment: More about global eval: http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/

Comment: The first code snippet should output `2` `5`, since direct call to `eval` is running in caller's scope?